# Conexao Postgresql com JDBC no eclipse

Tags: sql, postgresql, eclipse

Aparece no console:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:AulaFBD://localhost:5432/TrabalhoFBD
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at conexao.<init>(conexao.java:19)
    at Principal.main(Principal.java:5)
```

Comment: OIa Erika, bem vinda ao StackOverflow PT, tente elaborar melhor a sua pergunta para que a comunidade entenda melhor o seu problema e consiga te auxiliar de uma maneira mais adequada. Te sugiro de ler https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score -1):

**Agora aparece essa mensagem**

PostgreSQL JDBC Driver 42.2.5
Found in: jar:file:/home/erikasfs/Downloads/postgresql-42.2.5%20(1).jar!/org/postgresql/Driver.class

The PgJDBC driver is not an executable Java program.

You must install it according to the JDBC driver installation instructions for your application / container / appserver, then use it by specifying a JDBC URL of the form 
    jdbc:postgresql://
or using an application specific method.

See the PgJDBC documentation: http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/index.html

This command has had no effect.